How to perform admin operation on non-admin user WSL distro?
I have a WSL distro installed on a non-admin Windows account.
Some WSL operations require privilege elevation (e.g. --mount --bare).
But the admin account can't see the non-admin user's distro.
This github issue states that it is normal:

This is the expected behavior: Distributions are installed per user and not per machine.

So, how can I run my WSL elevated operation on the distro, beside granting admin rights to that user (which I do not wish to do)?
Environment:
Windows 10 22H2 [version 10.0.19045.4170]
WSL 2.1.5.0

You cannot. Those are the implications of this setup.

This question was raised in bug-report
Mounting a Linux disk requires administrator priviledges #6414.
The answer by user OneBlue was as follows :

When a partition is attached to WSL2, even though only the partition
is mounted, the entire disk has to be detached from Windows and
attached to WSL2.
By design, administrator access is required to do that, because users
have root access in WSL, so wsl --mount could be used to bypass the
filesystem ACL's if the user doesn't have administrator access.

This is a security consideration, because mounting the disk gives
the WSL user an administrator access to all the files on it, so
security is completely bypassed.
There exist products that allow running specific applications as
Administrator without the user knowing the administrator password.
Such a product can perhaps solve your problem, by running the
wsl --mount.
Some free products that do that :

RunAsTool

RunAsRob

Run As GUI
This link is to the Internet Archives, as the original website
has disappeared. You need to right-click on the Zip file to download.



The solution is to run WSL as an administrator, while the instance will be separate, it solves your problem in a secure way.

@Ramhound: Right - this jogged my memory, so I added more to my answer.

The problem is that if you run as admin, you are using a different account and cannot access the original account’s WSL distributions. This is not like regular UAC elevation with an admin account.

@DanielB: A workaround would perhaps be to install the distro as administrator to start with, and setup users with the utilities from my answer to run this distro as the administrator with --mount (or without).

@DanielB - Well if the action requires elevation and for security purposes WSL is separate for each user there is only one option to use the user with the capacity to elevate the process permissions

Thanks for the answers. I see now that there are no clear workarounds. I will favor duplicating the distro on the admin account, as it looks safer than opening an elevation route on the system.
